# Azure Application Gateway - Rewrite url path (strip prefix)

Tags: azure, url-rewriting

I have the following setup in my gateway:

https://example.org/office -> this maps to https://myapplication.example.org

Right now when going to https://example.org/office, Azure tries to fetch data from https://myapplication.example.org/office. I need it to remove the /office section from the uri (using a rewrite).

Sample urls - Wanted path after rewrite

https://example.org/office/files/123 -> /files/123

https://example.org/office/files/content/123 -> /files/content/123

I've tried the following rewrite but it doesn't work, I can't even save it. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

I'm getting the following error when I try to save it:

> Modified Path and Modified Query string does not follow supported syntax. Curly brackets have special meaning in HeaderValue field. To use a literal curly bracket please escape it with backslash().

Comment: Follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal

Comment: I was able to save in the same scenario with URL path value /{uri_path_2} ... but my scenario was not working

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution to work for me:

Pattern to Match in the condition (IF) should be: **/office/(.*)**

In the THEN you should set the URL path value: **{var_uri_path_1}**

Then it cuts the **/office** from the path and leave the rest. E.g. /office/files/content/123 becomes /files/content/123 and it even works if you have parameters like office/files/content/123?action=list&sortorder=descending

Se screenshot of the Azure Gateway Rewrite Rule here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, my problem was I was using the rewrite rules incorrectly. You have to use them each with {**var**_uri_path} for it to work.

My rule looked like this:
https://example.org/App01 -> https://example.org/nv01/App01

Rewrite type: **URL** 
Action type: **Set**
Components: **URL path**

URL path value: **nv01/{var_uri_path}**

[Rewrite Configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMiJu.png)

Comment: In your example, it's the opposite of what is asked. You simply add something to the path, not removing from the path.